Conditional schema not working as expected
I'm trying to write a JSON schema for a config file, so the config file object has a tasks array containing several properties, one of them being an enum "restart".
I want my configuration to have a "restartAttempts" property only if "restart" is set to "on-failure", so I thought I could use "if", "then" blocks in my schema, but it turns out that it's not working as expected, even if I provide "restart": "on-failure", I still get a syntax error in my lsp telling me property restartAttempts is not allowed. Here is the schema:
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "TMConfig",
  "description": "TaskMaster configuration file",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "tasks": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "The tasks to be executed",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "command": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "The executable to run"
          },
          "arguments": {
            "type": "array",
            "default": [],
            "description": "The arguments to pass to the executable\nDefault is []",
            "items": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "startAtLaunch": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": true,
            "description": "Wether or not to start the process(es) at launch\nDefault is true"
          },
          "instances": {
            "type": "number",
            "default": 1,
            "description": "The number of instances of the process to run\nDefault is 1",
            "minimum": 1
          },
          "restart": {
            "enum": ["always", "never", "on-failure", "unless-stopped"],
            "default": "on-failure",
            "description": "'always': always restart the process if it exits\n'never': never restart the process\n'on-failure': restart if the process exits with an error code\n'unless-stopped': restart the process except if the user stops it manually through the console\nDefault is 'on-failure'"
          },
          "expectedExitStatus": {
            "type": "number",
            "default": 0,
            "description": "The expected success exit status code for the process(es)\nDefault is 0"
          },
          "startTime": {
            "type": "number",
            "default": 0,
            "description": "The time to wait (in milliseconds) before considering that a process is sucessfuly started\nDefault is 0",
            "minimum": 0
          },
          "stopTime": {
            "type": "number",
            "default": 5000,
            "description": "The time to wait (in milliseconds) after a graceful stop before killing a process\nDefault is 5000",
            "minimum": 0
          },
          "stopSignal": {
            "enum": [
              "SIGINT",
              "SIGQUIT",
              "SIGTERM",
              "SIGUSR1",
              "SIGUSR2",
              "SIGSTOP",
              "SIGTSTP"
            ],
            "default": "SIGSTOP",
            "description": "The signal used to quit a process gracefully\nDefault is 'SIGSTOP'"
          },
          "stdout": {
            "enum": ["ignore", "inherit", "redirect"],
            "default": "redirect",
            "description": "'ignore': ignore stdout\n'inherit': show stdout on taskmaster console\n'redirect': redirect stdout to a log file\nDefault is 'redirect'"
          },
          "stderr": {
            "enum": ["ignore", "inherit", "redirect"],
            "default": "redirect",
            "description": "'ignore': ignore stderr\n'inherit': show stderr on taskmaster console\n'redirect': redirect stderr to a log file\nDefault is 'redirect'"
          },
          "logDir": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "/var/log/taskmaster",
            "description": "The path in which to save output log files\nDefault is /var/log/taskmaster"
          },
          "environment": {
            "type": "object",
            "default": {},
            "description": "Variables to pass as environment to the process(es)\nDefault is {}",
            "required": [],
            "additionalProperties": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "workingDirectory": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": ".",
            "description": "The working directory\nDefault is '.'"
          },
          "permissions": {
            "type": ["number", "null"],
            "default": null,
            "description": "The permissions umask to set before launching the program, or null to leave the permissions as they are\nDefault is null",
            "maximum": 777
          }
        },
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "restart": { "const": "on-failure" }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "restartAttempts": {
              "type": "number",
              "default": 5,
              "description": "The number of restart attempts (or 0 for infinite attemps) if 'restart' is set to 'on-failure'\nDefault is 5",
              "minimum": 0
            }
          }
        },
        "required": ["command"],
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "additionalItems": false
    }
  }
}

I'm using neovim with Mason and the jsonls lsp (vscode-json-language-server).
I checked if there was an available update in Mason / Lazy, but it seems to be up to date, but I'm doing the same as the JSON Schemas official example

It seem to work when enabling additionalProperties, but I don't want any other additional property

Solved using "unevaluatedProperties": false instead of "additionalProperties": false (see Json schema add property on if condition)

I recommend setting required keyword in the then statement.  Otherwise, your schema can have restart and restartAttempts but it will always evaluated to true if restartAttempts is missing or is misspelled.
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "restart": {
        "const": "on-failure"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": ["restartAttempts"],
    "properties": {
      "restartAttempts": {
        "type": "number",
        "default": 5,
        "description": "The number of restart attempts (or 0 for infinite attemps) if 'restart' is set to 'on-failure'\nDefault is 5",
        "minimum": 0
      }
    }
  }

without required, both of these are still passing validation because restartAttempts will only be evaluated if it's present, when not required.
{
    "restart": "on-failure",
    "restartAtttttempts": true
}

{
    "restart": "on-failure"
}


Yes, that was the desired behavior, sorry if I missexplained, I want the user to be able to configure restartAttempts only if restart is on-failure, but if they don't provide a restartAttempts it's still fine, my program uses a default value
